# Is always the ratio (number of commuting pairs of elements in a ring or a Lie algebra)/(the size of the ring or the Lie algebra) integer?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

(1) Is there a finite nilpotent ring $R$ such that the ratio 
$$c(R)=\frac{|\{(x,y)\in R\times R \; | \;  xy=yx\}}{|R|}$$
is not integer?

Edit 1: The nilpotent condition is put later.

Edit/Answer: Answer is negative as Frieder Ladisch nicely observed below. That is $c(R)$ is always an integer. Actually $c(R)$ is the number of conjugacy classes of the group $1+R$.

(2) Is there a finite  nilpotent Lie algebra $L$ such that the ratio 
$$c(L)=\frac{|\{(x,y)\in L\times L \; | \;  [x,y]=0\}}{|L|}$$
is not integer?

Edit: The nilpotent condition on the Lie Algebra is put later.

The motivation is that the same question for finite groups has negative answer.

Comment: What have you tried? in a Lie algebra of dimension $n$ over a field of cardinal $q$ such that every commuting pair is collinear, the number of commuting pairs is $q^{n+1}+q^n-q$, so the ratio is $q+1-1/q$. There are such examples with $n=2$ or $n=3$ (so, the smallest possible non-abelian Lie algebra is a counterexample!).

Comment: @YCor. I think I have missed another hypothesis that the Lie algebra should be nilpotent.

Comment: Counter examples for nilpotent Lie algebras will involve "small primes". If $p>n$, then $\exp$ is a well defined bijection from $N_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ to $U_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ (where $N_n$ and $U_n$ are upper triangular matrices with $0$'s and $1$'s on the diagonal respectively). The map $\exp$ takes sub-Lie-algebras to sub-groups and commuting pairs to commuting pairs.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer. Yes. By Lazard's correspondence there is a bijective map $\mathcal{L}$ from an arbitrary nilpotent finite dimensional Lie algebra $L$ over a finite field of characteristic $p$ of nilpotent
class less than $p$ to a finite $p$-group $G$ (of the same nilpotency class as $L$) such that $[x, y]^\mathcal{L} = [x^{\mathcal{L}}, y^{\mathcal{L}}]$ for all $x, y \in L$, where the right hand side is the usual group commutator $[a, b] = a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$. This implies that the answer to the question is negative for all such Lie algebras $L$.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer. In the meanwhile, the nilpotency class of a possible counterexample  should be at least $3$. I have proved the latter.

Comment: The title is written is the positive while the question is in the negative, which makes "a negative answer" quite ambiguous. It's more natural to ask everything in the positive.

Comment: @AlirezaAbdollahi I also got the nilpotency $\geq 3$ result. Proof for the curious: Let $L$ be a Lie algebra with nilpotency $2$. Let $Z$ be the center. Let $\ell=\dim L$ and $z=\dim Z$. We write $\bar{\ }$ for reduction from $L$ to $L/Z$. For $g \in L$, we have $[g,h]=0$ iff $\bar{h}$ is in $\mathrm{Ker}([\bar{g}, \ ] : L/Z \to Z)$. The dimension of the kernel is $\geq (\ell-z)-z=\ell-2z$. For each possible $\bar{g} \in L/Z$, this contributes $q^{\ell-2z} q^{2z}=|L|$ pairs $(g,h)$, since there are $q^z$ ways each to lift $\bar{g}$ and $\bar{h}$ to $L$. Sum over $\bar{g}$ to conclude.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer. I have a proof for a finite nilpotent Lie ring of nilpotent class $2$. I will publish it here tommorow, as it is now in my computer at university.

Comment: @YCor. I used "always" in the title so I have to write in positive. I wrote the question in the body in negative as my guess is that an example is elusive.

Comment: Anyway I initially understood from your last line that your claim is that there are counterexamples in the case of finite (nilpotent??) groups, while you mean the opposite.

Comment: ‎Let $L$ be a Lie ring such that $[L,L,L]=0$‎. ‎Then $c(L)$ is an integer‎.
‎
‎For amt $x\in L$‎, ‎define $[x]=\{x+[x,y] \;|\; y\in L\}$‎. ‎The latter set is an orbit of the equivalence relation $\sim$ on $L$ which is defined as follows‎:

Comment: $$x \sim y \Leftrightarrow \exists\; t\in L \;\;\;\; x+[x,t]=y.$$‎ 
‎We now prove that $\sim$ is reflexive‎, ‎symmetric and transitive‎.
‎
‎(1)  $x+[x,0]=x+0=x$ ($\sim$ is reflexive)‎.
‎\item If $x\sim y$‎, ‎then there exists $t\in L$ such that $x+[x,t]=y$‎. ‎Thus $[y,t]=[x+[x,t],t]=[x,t]+[x,t,t]$ which implies $[y,t]=[x,t]$‎.
‎So‎, ‎$x=y-[x,t]=y-[y,t]=y+[y,-t]$‎. ‎Thus $y\sim x$‎. ‎Hence $\sim$ is symmetric‎.

Comment: (2)  $\sim$ is transitive‎. ‎Let $x\sim y$ and $y\sim z$‎. ‎Then there exist $t,s\in L$ such that $x+[x,t]=y$ and $y+[y,s]=z$‎. ‎It follows that‎
‎\begin{align*}z=y+[y,s]&=&\\&x+[x,t]+[x+[x,t],s]=\\‎
‎&x+[x,t]+[x,s]+[x,t,s]=x+[x,t+s]‎.
‎\end{align*}‎
‎Thus $z=x+[x,t+s]$ and so $x\sim z$‎. 
‎
‎Thus‎, ‎$L$ is partitioned by $[x]$'s‎. ‎Suppose that $[x_1],\dots,[x_n]$ are all orbits of the equivalence relation $\sim$ on $L$‎.
‎Now note that is any Lie ring‎, ‎we have $|L:C_L(x)|=|[x]|$‎.
‎Therefore‎,

Comment: \begin{align*}‎
‎|\{(x,y)\in L\times L \;|\; [x,y]=0\}|&=&\\‎
‎&\sum_{x\in L} |C_L(x)|= \sum_{i=1}^{n} |C_L(x_i)||[x_i]|\\‎
‎&=\sum_{i=1}^n |C_L(x_i)||L:C_L(x)|=\sum_{i=1}^n |L|=n|L|‎.
‎\end{align*}‎
‎Hence the ratio is equal to $n$‎. ‎This completes the proof‎.

Comment: Well, for (1) the answer is the same as for groups, simply because $ 1+R $ is a group, and $(1+x)(1+y) = (1+y)(1+x)$ iff $ xy=yx $.